# Setter methods not being called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I've created a setter module that that should get called when anything is being stored into the _textColor variable but it isn't working, if I remove the new setter module and have synthesizer create default ones then the default ones will work. The problem with this is that when I have a variable called 'fillColor' I end up getting access to a different module called setFillColor:

I've omitted the bulk of code which is irrelevant
In my header file I have the following:

```
@interface ICADrawingObject : NSObject <NSCoding> {
@private
    NSColor                 *_textColor;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite, setter=setObjectTextColor:) NSColor* textColor;
```

In the implementation I have:

```
@synthesize textColor = _textColor;

-(void)setObjectTextColor:(NSColor *)textColor{
    NSLog(@"Text Old Color: %@",self.textColor);
    NSLog(@"Text New Color: %@",textColor);

    _textColor = textColor;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why are you changing the name of the setter? This is exceedingly rare, and may break parts of KVC (I haven't tested because this is such an unusual thing to do). Sometimes we change the name of the getter (specifically for booleans), but almost never the name of the setter.

Comment: Note also that there is no way to get a method to be run if you directly access your ivars. So when you say "when anything is being stored into the `_textColor` variable," that's impossible. You should use accessors everywhere (except init and dealloc). If it's purely for debugging, you can use LLDB "watchpoints" to watch when memory changes. But you can't cause code to run when you change an ivar without an accessor.

Comment: Tbh, I wanted to try and get the setter to work partly to save me work and also due to my colleagues use of variable names throughout the code which causes a lot of issues. Looking further into the code I find that a lot of the issues are occurring due to the bindings to the variable in the xib files, I think the best thing to do is just rename the variables and keep everything safe

Comment: This isn't really both "iphone" and "osx", is it? It's probably not relevant to your question, but using the right tags means you'll get the attention of the right answerers.

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this:

```
 -(void)setTextColor:(NSColor *)textColor{
    if (_textColor != textColor) {
    [_textColor release];
    _textColor = [textColor retain];

 }
```

Comment: That uses the default method, I need to get it to use the setObjectTextColor: method

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
@interface ICADrawingObject : NSObject {
    NSColor *_textColor;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain, setter=setObjectTextColor:) NSColor *textColor;
@end

@implementation ICADrawingObject
@synthesize textColor = _textColor;

-(void)setObjectTextColor:(NSColor *)aColor{
    NSLog(@"Text Old Color: %@",_textColor);
    NSLog(@"Text New Color: %@",aColor);
    if( _textColor != aColor ) {
        [_textColor release];
        _textColor = [aColor retain];
    }
    _textColor = aColor;
}

@end
```

Thereafter, if we do this:

```
ICADrawingObject *obj = [ICADrawingObject new];
obj.textColor = [NSColor blackColor];
```

then this should print to the console, as evidence that the custom setter is being called:

```
2012-09-19 08:37:43.605 test323[67540:303] Text Old Color: (null)
2012-09-19 08:37:43.606 test323[67540:303] Text New Color: NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1
```

By the way, there's no need for the `@private` designation on ivars.  You can control the visibility now by declaring ivars in the implementation.